# What is the best compression scheme for small data such as 1.66kBytes?

Tags: c++, lossless-compression

This data is stored in an array (using C++) and is a repetition of 125 bits each one varying from the other. It also has 8 messages of 12 ASCII characters each at the end. Please suggest if I should use differential compression within the array and if so how?

Or should I apply some other compression scheme onto the whole array?

Comment: Why do you need to compress it?

Comment: for saving bandwidth and increasing refresh rate in TDMA transmission

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed description of the data, i.e. the fields, and the range in which you expect them to vary?

Comment: @FMark
its aircraft information e.g latitude,longitude ,speed,altitude,heading,id,type etc..

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can compress data that has some sort of predictability or redundancy.  Dictionary based compression (e.g. ZIP style algorithms) traditionally don't work well on small chunks of data because of the need to share the selected dictionary.

In the past, when I have compressed very small chunks of data with somewhat predictable patterns, I have used [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) with a custom dictionary.  Rather than embed the dictionary in the actual data, I hard-coded the dictionary in every program that needs to (de)compress the data.  SharpZipLib gives you both options: custom dictionary, and keep dictionary separate from the data.

Again this will only work well if you can predict some patterns to your data *ahead of time* so that you can create an appropriate compression dictionary, and it's feasible for the dictionary itself to be separate from the compressed data.

Comment: Well Eric.J thanks for your answer
actually i need to transmit the compressed data every 4 seconds and actually the 125 bits data isnt much prbabilistic

Comment: @Mujtaba: What kind of data is represented in the 125 bits?

Comment: its aircraft information e.g latitude,longitude ,speed,altitude,heading,id,type etc..

Comment: @Mujtaba: That kind of data is actually **highly** compressible if you're currently sending it as text.  There are mostly digits and the decimal symbol.  Even if binary, you should still get good compression.  Headings are only 0-359, airspeed and altitude fall in narrow ranges as does lat/long.  I suspect SharpZipLib with custom dictionary would work well.  Lempel-Ziv probably would not as there's not a lot of data in a given stream.

Comment: @Eric   right now i am generating this data randomly and storing in an array.This array is then transmitted after appending header and trailer through RS-232 in lab model but actual tx will be over air in real time. Also i wanted to ask you that that as array carrying the radar data has 100 aircraft tracks dataplus 8 messages of 12 ascii ch each,will compression achieved by tranmitting inter track difference be more effective than applying compression as whole on the array?

Comment: A difference-based compression should be much more effective since the aircraft will tend to be the same (only occasionally will one be added or drop off) and the coordinates will be very similar.  However, if you lose one packet of data with a difference strategy, difference compression breaks down (what if you lose the packet that indicates a new aircraft is in the sector...).  Having a "key" frame that contains full data every few seconds would solve that.

Comment: @Eric J.Now i am implementing differential compression on two consecutive arrays containing 13268 bits each and i assume that the resultant array would be much more feasible for LZ compression 
any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

**You haven't given us enough information to help you.**  However, I can highly recommend the book [*Text Compression*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139119914) by Bell, Cleary, and Witten.  Don't be fooled by the title; "Text" here just means "lossless"—all the techniques apply to binary data.  Because the book is expensive you might try to get it on interlibrary loan.

Also, don't overlook the obvious Burrows-Wheeler (bzip2) or Lempel-Ziv (gzip, zlib) techniques.  It's quite possible that one of these techniques will work well for your application, so **before investigating alternatives, try compressing your data with standard tools**.

Comment: Thanks RAMSEY 
do these bzip2 and LZ techniques work for array data?

Comment: @Mujtaba absolutely yes: any sequence of bytes in memory.

Comment: would'nt applying these compression techniques make the bit stream longer because these some over heads for makingcompression possible?

Comment: @Mujtaba it depends what's in the bit streams.  Bit streams with redundancy get shorter.  The total overhead for compression can easily be reduced to one bit, however, so it shouldn't be a concern.  Whether standard techniques give you actual compression is an experimental question.

Comment: @Norman Now i am implementing differential compression on two consecutive arrays containing 13268 bits each and i assume that the resultant array would be much more feasible for LZ compression any suggestions?? –